# move data from a table to another with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What's the most 'correct' way to move data from a table (MySql) to another table with Laravel (8)? I've found some people using `replicate()` but I don't know if that's the best choice. Is there some, or any, best pratice for that?

Also, if I just want to move some columns from table1 to table2 the approach would be the same?

thx

Comment: DB::table('destination_table')->insert(
    DB::table('source_table')->get()->toArray()
);

Comment: @KarlHill I like it, this way I could even pick the columns with `pluck()` or `select()`. thx

Comment: Please define the crieria for determining the best method!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only need to move a few rows you can use `replicate()` but if you need to move several rows, then the option suggested by Karl Hill will be better:

```php
// here you can create a complex query to filter the data you want to move
$dataToCopy = DB::table('source_table')->get()->toArray();

DB::table('destination_table')->insert( $dataToCopy );
```

Comment: For some reason `insert()` didn't work for me, so I used the method `insertUsing()` instead. My query was `DB::table('target_table')->insertUsing(['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3', 'column_4'], DB::table('origin_table')
            ->selectRaw('id as column_1, foo as column_2, bar as column_3, 50 as column_4')`. This way I could tailor the columns as much as I wanted